# using react and json to upload images to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have a form in a react compnent that includes an image. This component has an associated state for the form, it is quite a large and complex form with many nested arrays of sub elements that vary in length, which is why I do not want to use FormData().

```
state = { 
        recipe: {
            title: "",
            image: null,
            ingredient_groups: [
                {
                    title: "",
                    ingredients: [
                        {
                            name: "",
                            measurement_metric: "",
                            measurement_imperial: ""
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

The state is updated with an onChange handler for the input field like the following

```
let {recipe} = this.state;
recipe.image = event.target.files[0];
this.setState({recipe});
```

This is then sent via an axios post request,

```
let {recipe} = this.state;

axios.post('/api/v1/recipe', {recipe: recipe}).then((result) => {
        console.log(result.status)
})
```

in rails I have a params method set up for the allowed params

```
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title,
                               :image,  
                               {ingredient_groups: [
                                   :id,
                                   :title,
                                   {ingredients: [
                                       :id,
                                       :name,
                                       :measurement_metric,
                                       :measurement_imperial
                                   ]}
                               ]})
end
```

however I am getting nil for recipe_params[:image] when I try to save it into active storage like this:

```
@recipe.image.attach(recipe_params[:image])
```

Is what Im doing even possible? Or is the only way to transmit this via a FormData object on the post. I would really prefer this to be done via a pure json method.

Comment: what do you get if you log out the params in your controller? `puts params[:recipe]`

Comment: I get everything correctly described, excpet for image which is described as `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess `

Comment: can you throw a `byebug` in there and get more details on what that hash contains?  also maybe `console.log(recipe.image)` in that event handler to see what you're passing in

Comment: so, I was able to find https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata which saved me the hassle of having to build a nested form data and with that I am successfully able to upload the image! Its not the pure json way I wanted, but it works. Thanks for helping though!

Comment: cool no worries - I was just going to say there's probably more to consider here if you're trying to upload an actual image file

Answer (score 0):

using https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata I was able to successfully change my react state object into a FormData Object, and then post this to my endpoint and it has worked as expected